# Cannot install Ubuntu -- Wubi does not currently support EFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 15.10, wubi

I have the `.iso` image of Ubuntu 15.10 that a friend gave to me. I have a pre-installed Windows 10. When I mount the image and run `wubi.exe`, it gives the following error:

> Wubi does not currently support EFI.

Please tell me how to install (dual-boot) Ubuntu (with Windows). My FastBoot service is off and Windows is installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Wubi only supports Windows 7 and lower except for Windows ME.

Comment: So you mean I need another copy of Ubuntu to dual boot along with WinX?

Comment: No, you can use that disk. You need to create unallocated space on your disk and install Ubuntu in that space.

Comment: Can you please make a more detailed answer altogether? I'm not a very technical person, so please ...

Comment: You can not easily use qubi, if at all, you have to do a standard installation. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: The iso of 15.10 does not contain a wubi.exe. Do you mean 15.04 or 14.10 ? But it does not matter this version does not work at all. So avoid Wubi or try a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a different partition through windows and then installing with custom installation(when you boot with the USB or CD there is an option after you press ''Install Ubuntu'' instead of install alongside Windows or delete windows). Here is a program that you can try using and a guide along with it: [Safely Create Partition for Windows 10 with Free Software](http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/create-partition-windows-10-0528.html)

Comment: @GoldHaloWings I just provided the site's title, no need to change it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can't use wubi with EFI enable.

Try to disable EFI from your bios and do the followings:

**Installation with wubi**: requires to [resize your NTFS windoze partition](http://www.howto-connect.com/windows-10-disk-management/) from [Windoze Disk Management](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/7-ways-to-open-disk-management-in-windows-10.html)  to make free space and then you must [create a **second** NTFS partition for Ubuntu](http://www.howto-connect.com/windows-10-disk-management/), Note that wubi will install Ubuntu on the second NTFS partition and Ubuntu **will be slower** since NTFS is **not** a GNU/Linux file system, you will see the instructions just choose what you want, dual boot etc.

**Installation without wubi** with **EFI enable**: requires to [resize your NTFS partition of windoze](http://www.howto-connect.com/windows-10-disk-management/) to make free space for Ubuntu and set your pc bios to **boot from the cd** now all you need to do is boot from cd and follow the instructions, is pretty straightforward, will also ask you about dual boot.

*Ubuntu on Ext4 partition is **much faster** since is a file system for GNU/Linux.*

Installation without wubi is the best way to go. *(recommended)*

Comment: Probably, it is possible to disable UEFI mode with BIOS settings. But Windows is still in UEFI mode. In my case, Windows doesn't boot with disabled UEFI mode. This is not really an advantage if you try an installation with Wubi. And a second question occurred: Why does Wubi require to resize a NTFS partition? The advantage of Wubi is that you can use your Windows partitions without changing anything.

Comment: An OS relies on a boot loader written for a specific firmware type (BIOS or EFI, for instance). If Windows is booting in EFI mode, switching the computer to boot in BIOS mode will either render Windows *unbootable* (if EFI-mode booting is completely disabled) or have no effect (if BIOS mode becomes a boot option, but not a requirement). Although there are ways to install a new (BIOS-mode) boot loader to work around this issue, the process is complex and fraught with danger, so it's not something I recommend attempting without significant motivation.